# Run command for all files in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have the following command on the build-server as a part of the build process:

```
os.system ('signtool sign /a /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "%s\\*.exe"' % (dir) )
```

This command signs each executable file in the specified directory. Is there a way to run this command in parallel for each executable file using Python? Is there something like [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) for Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use threads. [This tutorial](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/python-python-threads-a-first-example.html) shows how to do something similar to what you're asking for using threads.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) could be of help here?

Specifically, `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` might be relevant to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are perfectly sensible ways of approaching things from the Python side, eg

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def processFile(x):
    return os.system('ls '+x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    files=['foo','foo.py','foo.cpp','foo.txt','foo.bar']
    result = pool.map(processFile, files)
    print 'Results are', result
```

But if you're using the shell anyway, you might want to consider using [Gnu Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) on the shell side, which runs like xargs but does the individual tasks in parallel, with options to control how many jobs can run simultaneously, etc.